# Visual Studio session management

Tags: visual-studio-2012, session-management, suo

When working on a particular bug or feature I like to have a certain set of files open (among other things).

When I switch between tasks I don't like to lose all this context - so I found that I can make a copy of the .suo file from the Visual Studio solution folder. Whenever I want get back to a certain context I simply over-write the original .suo file with the backup copy.

Is there an easier way to accomplish what I want? Any add-ons or extensions, for example some kind of session manager extension?

Note that I am not referring to things such as the *Window Layouts*, which as far as I know can already be saved by using the existing Import/Export Settings option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Favorite Documents](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d4ab8421-147f-4416-8038-d5f7fdcf6a56) extension lets you save currently opened files to a group and later re-open them.